# Problem converting Silverlight 3 to 4

Tags: silverlight, exception

I am currently trying to convert a Silverlight 3 application to Silverlight 4 and I am running into a problem. Everything compiles correctly but when I run it I get an error at about 70% loading. Im confused because its a javascript error I'm pretty sure.

throw new Error(

> "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Set
>   property
>   'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style'
>   threw an exception. [Line: 46 Position: 53]
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator)
>
> at
>   Project.Page.InitializeComponent()
>
> at Project.Page..ctor()
>     at
>   Project.App.Application_Startup(Object
>   sender, StartupEventArgs e)
>
> at
>   MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32
>   typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate,
>   Object sender, Object args)
>
> at
>   MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr
>   unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs,
>   Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32
>   actualArgsTypeIndex, String
>   eventName)"

);

Any idea on what would be causing this and how where I would look to fix it?

Comment: It's a Silverlight error, most likely relating to a change in styling. Apparently in your main page (Line: 46 Column: 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app.xaml file (Line: 46 Position: 53) - probably a style is not compatible with the new version? Can you post a fragment from app.xaml around that line?