# Error Loading Component

Tags: silverlight

I'm converting a Silverlight 3 project to Silverlight 4. I recently got the project able to run, but I am running into problems instantiating a search window. VS threw the following error at me:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception. [Line: 242 Position: 46]   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at ESM.Visualization.SearchWindow.InitializeComponent()
   at ESM.Visualization.SearchWindow..ctor(Map mapWindow, String addressServiceUrl, String projectServiceUrl)
   at ESM.Visualization.MainPage.InstantiateSearchWindow()
   at ESM.Visualization.MainPage.MapWindow_Progress(Object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map.layersProgressHandler(Object sender, ProgressEventArgs args)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.LayerCollection.layer_OnProgress(Object sender, ProgressEventArgs args)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Layer.ProgressHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ProgressEventArgs args)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Layer.OnProgress(Int32 progress)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.DynamicLayer.bitmap_DownloadProgress(Object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e, Image img, EventHandler`1 onProgressEventHandler, Int32 id)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.DynamicLayer.<>c__DisplayClass7.<getSourceComplete>b__4(Object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I researched the error and tried re-installing Silverlight in accordance to [this solution](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/195607.aspx/1). But the error still occurred. I looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166533/problem-converting-silverlight-3-to-4), but my App.xaml is hardly 242 lines. Here's my MainPage.xaml at around line 242:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <esriToolkit:Navigation x:Name="MapNavigation" Margin="5" Map="{Binding ElementName=MapWindow}" Visibility="Collapsed"  />
            <!--<esri:ScaleBar x:Name="MainScaleBar" Margin="5" MapUnit="DecimalDegrees" Foreground="Black" 
                Map="{Binding ElementName=MapWindow}"
                DisplayUnit="Miles" Visibility="Visible" />-->
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the .xaml for the search window I am trying to instantiate (at around line 242):

```
<grid:AgDataGrid x:Name="grdAddressResults" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ColumnsAutoWidth="True"
                                 ShowTotals="False" FocusMode="Row" FocusedRowChanged="grdResults_FocusedRowChanged"
                                 IsMultiSelect="False" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                <grid:AgDataGrid.Columns>
                                    <grid:AgDataGridColumn FieldName="Address" />
                                    <grid:AgDataGridColumn FieldName="X" Visible="False" />
                                    <grid:AgDataGridColumn FieldName="Y" Visible="False" />
                                </grid:AgDataGrid.Columns>
                                <grid:AgDataGrid.TotalSummary>
                                    <grid:AgDataGridSummaryItem FieldName="Address" SummaryType="Count" Title="Matches Found" />
                                </grid:AgDataGrid.TotalSummary>
                            </grid:AgDataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you please show the XAML code around the lines mentioned by the Exception message: [Line: 242 Position: 46]

Comment: I have already provided the XAML code.

Comment: Which of the lines is the 242?

Comment: `</StackPanel>` is line 242 of the MainPage.xaml and `</grid:AgDataGrid ...>` is line 242 of the SearchWindow.xaml.

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells

> Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.

Though this is not in the code you displayed - but I am almost sure you will find something like this somewhere in your code:

```
<SomeControl Style="MyCoolStyle" ... />
```

where it should be:

```
<SomeControl Style="{StaticResource MyCoolStyle}" ... />
```